# How to hide first column when there are colspan's in the body

Tags: jquery, css

I want to hide the first column of this table. I have random `rowspans` and `colspans`.

The snippet here using jQuery does well for `colspan`s but fails for `rowspan`.

```js
$(function() {
  var colIndexToHide = 1;

  $("tr").each(function(i, tr) {
    var cindex = -1;
    var done = false;
    
    $(tr).find("td").each(function(j, td) {
      if (done) return;
      
      if (cindex + td.colSpan >= colIndexToHide) {
        if (td.colSpan > 1) {
          td.colSpan--;
        } else {
          $(td).hide();
        }
        
        done = true;
      }
      
      cindex += td.colSpan;
    });
  });
});

$(function() {
  var colIndexToHide = 1;

  $("tr").each(function(i, tr) {
    var cindex = -1;
    var done = false;
    
    $(tr).find("th").each(function(j, th) {
      if (done) return;
      
      if (cindex + th.colSpan >= colIndexToHide) {
        if (th.colSpan > 1) {
          th.colSpan--;
        } else {
          $(th).hide();
        }
        
        done = true;
        
      }
      
      cindex += th.colSpan;
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0" summary="" class="table test" frame="border" border="1" rules="all">
  <col style="width:7.272727272727273%" />
  <col style="width:12.727272727272727%" />
  <col style="width:7.272727272727273%" />
  <col style="width:9.090909090909092%" />
  <col style="width:9.090909090909092%" />
  <col style="width:9.090909090909092%" />
  <col style="width:9.090909090909092%" />
  <col style="width:9.090909090909092%" />
  <col style="width:9.090909090909092%" />
  <col style="width:9.090909090909092%" />
  <col style="width:9.090909090909092%" />
  <thead class="thead" style="text-align:left;">
    <tr class="row">
      <th class="entry cellrowborder" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:top;" id="d362e36">A</th>
      <th class="entry cellrowborder" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:top;" id="d362e38">B</th>
      <th class="entry cellrowborder" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:top;" id="d362e40">C</th>
      <th class="entry cellrowborder" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:top;" id="d362e42"> </th>
      <th class="entry cellrowborder" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:top;" id="d362e44"> </th>
      <th class="entry cellrowborder" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:top;" id="d362e46"> </th>
      <th class="entry cellrowborder" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:top;" id="d362e48"> </th>
      <th class="entry cellrowborder" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:top;" id="d362e50"> </th>
      <th class="entry cellrowborder" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:top;" id="d362e52"> </th>
      <th class="entry cellrowborder" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:top;" id="d362e54"> </th>
      <th class="entry cellrowborder" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:top;" id="d362e56"> </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="tbody">
    <tr class="row">
      <td class="entry cellrowborder" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;" headers="d362e36 ">off03</td>
      <td class="entry cellrowborder" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;" headers="d362e38 ">
        <span class="xref">perspiciatis</span>
      </td>
      <td class="entry cellrowborder" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;" headers="d362e40 ">7:0</td>
      <td class="entry cellrowborder" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:top;" headers="d362e42 ">dolore </td>
      <td class="entry cellrowborder reserved" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:top;" headers="d362e44 "> </td>
      <td class="entry cellrowborder" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:top;" headers="d362e46 ">magna </td>
      <td class="entry cellrowborder" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:top;" headers="d362e48 ">cupidatat </td>
      <td class="entry cellrowborder reserved" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:top;" headers="d362e50 "> </td>
      <td class="entry cellrowborder reserved" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:top;" headers="d362e52 "> </td>
      <td class="entry cellrowborder reserved" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:top;" headers="d362e54 "> </td>
      <td class="entry cellrowborder" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:top;" headers="d362e56 ">magna </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row">
      <td class="entry cellrowborder reserved" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;" headers="d362e36 ">
        <p class="p">off04</p>
        <p class="p">...</p>
        <p class="p">off26</p>
      </td>
      <td class="entry cellrowborder reserved" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;" headers="d362e38 ">amet</td>
      <td class="entry cellrowborder reserved" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;" headers="d362e40 "> </td>
      <td class="entry cellrowborder reserved" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;" headers="d362e42 "> </td>
      <td class="entry cellrowborder reserved" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;" headers="d362e44 "> </td>
      <td class="entry cellrowborder reserved" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;" headers="d362e46 "> </td>
      <td class="entry cellrowborder reserved" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;" headers="d362e48 "> </td>
      <td class="entry cellrowborder reserved" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;" headers="d362e50 "> </td>
      <td class="entry cellrowborder reserved" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;" headers="d362e52 "> </td>
      <td class="entry cellrowborder reserved" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;" headers="d362e54 "> </td>
      <td class="entry cellrowborder reserved" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;" headers="d362e56 "> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row">
      <td class="entry cellrowborder" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;" headers="d362e36 ">off27</td>
      <td class="entry cellrowborder" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;" headers="d362e38 ">
        <span class="xref">rem</span>
      </td>
      <td class="entry cellrowborder" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;" headers="d362e40 ">7:0</td>
      <td class="entry cellrowborder reserved" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:top;" headers="d362e42 "> </td>
      <td class="entry cellrowborder reserved" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:top;" headers="d362e44 "> </td>
      <td class="entry cellrowborder reserved" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:top;" headers="d362e46 "> </td>
      <td class="entry cellrowborder reserved" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:top;" headers="d362e48 "> </td>
      <td class="entry cellrowborder" colspan="2" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:top;" headers="d362e50 d362e52 ">voluptatem </td>
      <td class="entry cellrowborder" colspan="2" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:top;" headers="d362e54 d362e56 ">magna </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row">
      <td class="entry cellrowborder" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;" headers="d362e36 ">off28</td>
      <td class="entry cellrowborder" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;" headers="d362e38 ">
        <span class="xref">ullamco</span>
      </td>
      <td class="entry cellrowborder" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;" headers="d362e40 ">7:0</td>
      <td class="entry cellrowborder reserved" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:top;" headers="d362e42 "> </td>
      <td class="entry cellrowborder reserved" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:top;" headers="d362e44 "> </td>
      <td class="entry cellrowborder reserved" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:top;" headers="d362e46 "> </td>
      <td class="entry cellrowborder reserved" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:top;" headers="d362e48 "> </td>
      <td class="entry cellrowborder" colspan="2" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:top;" headers="d362e50 d362e52 ">corporis</td>
      <td class="entry cellrowborder" colspan="2" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:top;" headers="d362e54 d362e56 ">laudantium</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row">
      <td class="entry cellrowborder reserved" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;" headers="d362e36 ">
        <p class="p">off29</p>
        <p class="p">...</p>
        <p class="p">off30</p>
      </td>
      <td class="entry cellrowborder reserved" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;" headers="d362e38 ">minim</td>
      <td class="entry cellrowborder reserved" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;" headers="d362e40 "> </td>
      <td class="entry cellrowborder reserved" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;" headers="d362e42 "> </td>
      <td class="entry cellrowborder reserved" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;" headers="d362e44 "> </td>
      <td class="entry cellrowborder reserved" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;" headers="d362e46 "> </td>
      <td class="entry cellrowborder reserved" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;" headers="d362e48 "> </td>
      <td class="entry cellrowborder reserved" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;" headers="d362e50 "> </td>
      <td class="entry cellrowborder reserved" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;" headers="d362e52 "> </td>
      <td class="entry cellrowborder reserved" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;" headers="d362e54 "> </td>
      <td class="entry cellrowborder reserved" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;" headers="d362e56 "> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row">
      <td class="entry cellrowborder" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;" headers="d362e36 ">off31</td>
      <td class="entry cellrowborder" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;" headers="d362e38 ">
        <span class="xref">incididunt </span>
      </td>
      <td class="entry cellrowborder" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;" headers="d362e40 ">7:0</td>
      <td class="entry cellrowborder reserved" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:top;" headers="d362e42 "> </td>
      <td class="entry cellrowborder reserved" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:top;" headers="d362e44 "> </td>
      <td class="entry cellrowborder reserved" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:top;" headers="d362e46 "> </td>
      <td class="entry cellrowborder reserved" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:top;" headers="d362e48 "> </td>
      <td class="entry cellrowborder" colspan="2" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:top;" headers="d362e50 d362e52 ">exercitation </td>
      <td class="entry cellrowborder" colspan="2" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:top;" headers="d362e54 d362e56 ">aute </td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="row">
      <td class="entry cellrowborder" rowspan="4" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;" headers="d362e36 ">off33</td>
      <td class="entry cellrowborder" rowspan="4" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;" headers="d362e38 ">
        <span class="xref">asdfsd</span>
      </td>
      <td class="entry cellrowborder" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;" headers="d362e40 ">7:0</td>
      <td class="entry cellrowborder reserved" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:top;" headers="d362e42 "> </td>
      <td class="entry cellrowborder reserved" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:top;" headers="d362e44 "> </td>
      <td class="entry cellrowborder reserved" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:top;" headers="d362e46 "> </td>
      <td class="entry cellrowborder reserved" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:top;" headers="d362e48 "> </td>
      <td class="entry cellrowborder" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:top;" headers="d362e50 ">pscipon</td>
      <td class="entry cellrowborder" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:top;" headers="d362e52 ">oclcugious</td>
      <td class="entry cellrowborder" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:top;" headers="d362e54 ">qumpan</td>
      <td class="entry cellrowborder reserved" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:top;" headers="d362e56 "> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row">
      <td class="entry cellrowborder" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;" headers="d362e40 ">15:8</td>
      <td class="entry cellrowborder reserved" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:top;" headers="d362e42 "> </td>
      <td class="entry cellrowborder reserved" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:top;" headers="d362e44 "> </td>
      <td class="entry cellrowborder reserved" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:top;" headers="d362e46 "> </td>
      <td class="entry cellrowborder reserved" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:top;" headers="d362e48 "> </td>
      <td class="entry cellrowborder reserved" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:top;" headers="d362e50 "> </td>
      <td class="entry cellrowborder reserved" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:top;" headers="d362e52 "> </td>
      <td class="entry cellrowborder reserved" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:top;" headers="d362e54 "> </td>
      <td class="entry cellrowborder reserved" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:top;" headers="d362e56 "> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row">
      <td class="entry cellrowborder" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;" headers="d362e40 ">23:16</td>
      <td class="entry cellrowborder reserved" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:top;" headers="d362e42 "> </td>
      <td class="entry cellrowborder reserved" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:top;" headers="d362e44 "> </td>
      <td class="entry cellrowborder reserved" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:top;" headers="d362e46 "> </td>
      <td class="entry cellrowborder reserved" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:top;" headers="d362e48 "> </td>
      <td class="entry cellrowborder reserved" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:top;" headers="d362e50 "> </td>
      <td class="entry cellrowborder reserved" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:top;" headers="d362e52 "> </td>
      <td class="entry cellrowborder reserved" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:top;" headers="d362e54 "> </td>
      <td class="entry cellrowborder reserved" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:top;" headers="d362e56 "> </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

([*fiddle*](http://jsfiddle.net/ep9q15w7/1/))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First some improvements for your current code:

- You can exit an `.each()` loop with `return true`. There is no need for the boolean `done`
- You can select both `td` and `th` in one go with `"td,th"` as selector. No need for code repetition.

Then, to implement support for `rowspan`, the idea is to keep track for each column, whether there is still a row "spanning" into the currently iterated row. For this you can use an array, where each at index you keep the remaining spanning-height for the corresponding column.

Below a snippet that implements this. It also provides an input box where you can type the number of the column to hide:

```js
function deleteColumn(table, colIndexToHide) {
    var rowspans = [];
    
    $("tr", table).each(function (i, tr) {
        var cindex = 0;
        $(tr).children("th,td").each(function (j, cell) {
            while (rowspans[cindex]) {
                rowspans[cindex++]--;
            }
            if (cindex > colIndexToHide) return false;
            var next = cindex + +cell.colSpan;
            while (cindex < next) {
                rowspans[cindex++] = cell.rowSpan - 1;
            }
            if (cindex > colIndexToHide) {
                if (+cell.colSpan > 1) {
                    cell.colSpan--;
                } else {
                    $(cell).hide();
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    });    
}

$("button").click(function() {
    deleteColumn($("table"), +$("#inp").val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0" class="table test" frame="border" border="1" rules="all">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>0</th>
            <th>1</th>
            <th>2</th>
            <th>3</th>
            <th>4</th>
            <th>5</th>
            <th>6</th>
            <th>7</th>
            <th>8</th>
            <th>9</th>
            <th>10</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>off03</td>
            <td><span class="xref">perspiciatis</span></td>
            <td>7:0</td>
            <td>dolore </td>
            <td></td>
            <td>magna </td>
            <td>cupidatat </td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>magna </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <p class="p">off04</p>
                <p class="p">...</p>
                <p class="p">off26</p>
            </td>
            <td>amet</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>off27</td>
            <td><span class="xref">rem</span></td>
            <td>7:0</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td colspan="2">voluptatem</td>
            <td colspan="2">magna</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>off28</td>
            <td><span class="xref">ullamco</span></td>
            <td>7:0</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td colspan="2">corporis</td>
            <td colspan="2">laudantium</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <p class="p">off29</p>
                <p class="p">...</p>
                <p class="p">off30</p>
            </td>
            <td>minim</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>off31</td>
            <td><span class="xref">incididunt</span></td>
            <td>7:0</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td colspan="2">exercitation</td>
            <td colspan="2">aute</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="4">off33</td>
            <td rowspan="4"><span class="xref">asdfsd</span></td>
            <td>7:0</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>pscipon</td>
            <td>oclcugious</td>
            <td>qumpan</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>15:8</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>23:16</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

Column to hide: <input id="inp" value="0"> (be aware that hidden columns still have a number)<br>
<button>hide column</button>
```

### Version without jQuery

Elements can be selected with `document.querySelector()`. Event listeners can be attached with `.addEventListener()`. Elements can be hidden with `.style.display = "none"`. HTML element lists can be iterated using a `for..of` loop (and a `break` to exit):

```js
function deleteColumn(table, colIndexToHide) {
    const rowspans = [];
    
    for (const tr of table.rows) {
        let cindex = 0;
        for (const cell of tr.cells) {
            while (rowspans[cindex]) {
                rowspans[cindex++]--;
            }
            if (cindex > colIndexToHide) break;
            const next = cindex + +cell.colSpan;
            while (cindex < next) {
                rowspans[cindex++] = cell.rowSpan - 1;
            }
            if (cindex > colIndexToHide) {
                if (+cell.colSpan > 1) {
                    cell.colSpan--;
                } else {
                    cell.style.display = "none";
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }  
}

document.querySelector("#btnhide").addEventListener("click", function() {
    deleteColumn(document.querySelector("table.test"), 
                +document.querySelector("#inp").value);
});
```

```html
<table cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0" class="table test" frame="border" border="1" rules="all">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>0</th>
            <th>1</th>
            <th>2</th>
            <th>3</th>
            <th>4</th>
            <th>5</th>
            <th>6</th>
            <th>7</th>
            <th>8</th>
            <th>9</th>
            <th>10</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>off03</td>
            <td><span class="xref">perspiciatis</span></td>
            <td>7:0</td>
            <td>dolore </td>
            <td></td>
            <td>magna </td>
            <td>cupidatat </td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>magna </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <p class="p">off04</p>
                <p class="p">...</p>
                <p class="p">off26</p>
            </td>
            <td>amet</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>off27</td>
            <td><span class="xref">rem</span></td>
            <td>7:0</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td colspan="2">voluptatem</td>
            <td colspan="2">magna</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>off28</td>
            <td><span class="xref">ullamco</span></td>
            <td>7:0</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td colspan="2">corporis</td>
            <td colspan="2">laudantium</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <p class="p">off29</p>
                <p class="p">...</p>
                <p class="p">off30</p>
            </td>
            <td>minim</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>off31</td>
            <td><span class="xref">incididunt</span></td>
            <td>7:0</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td colspan="2">exercitation</td>
            <td colspan="2">aute</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="4">off33</td>
            <td rowspan="4"><span class="xref">asdfsd</span></td>
            <td>7:0</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>pscipon</td>
            <td>oclcugious</td>
            <td>qumpan</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>15:8</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>23:16</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>


Column to hide: <input id="inp" value="0"> (be aware that hidden columns still have a number)<br>
<button id="btnhide">hide column</button>
```

Comment: It works perfectly. May I ask another question, how can i convert this Jquery into JavaScript (is there an easy way to do that)? before posting the question I didn't realize that I would require JS too. Many thanks!

Comment: I added non-jQuery version to my answer. I should mention that jQuery *is* JavaScript, and whether you include that library or not does not influence which other "vanilla JS" features are available to you.